# Use builder pattern in Spring for rest api

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, builder-pattern

I'm creating rest api in spring boot and I need suggestions on whats the best approach to use builder pattern in Spring because I'm new to Spring.

**Product.java** (Database entity)

```
public class Product{
    private String name;
    private String sku;

    //getter-setter
}
```

**ProductBuilder.java**

```
public interface ProductBuilder {
    public ProductBuilder setBasicDetails(String name, String sku)
}
```

**ProductBuilderImpl.java**

```
public class ProductBuilderImpl implements ProductBuilder{

    // issue is with creating new object of `Product`

    @Override
    public ProductBuilder setBasicDetails(String name, String sku) {
        product.setName(name);
        product.setSku(sku);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Suggestions for creating new object of `Product` for multiple `HTTPRequest` in following approaches.

---

**Approach 1**: `@Autowired` ProductBuilder.

```
@Service
public class xyzServiceImpl implements xyzService{

    @Autowired
    private ProductBuilder productBuilder;

    // business logic
}
```

`xyzServiceImpl` is singleton so `ProductBuilder` will create only one object of `Product` and its shared between `Thread`/`Request`

**HTTP Request 1**: `Product` is initialized with `id = null` > Perform save > `id = 123`

**HTTP Request 2**: Got the object`[Product.id = 123]` updated in `HTTP Request 1` but **I want new object every time**.

So I tried following solution but not working

```
@Configuration
public class ModelBuilderConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public ProductBuilder productBuilder(){
        return new ProductBuilderImpl();
    }
}
```

and creating `initMethod` in `ProductBuilderImpl` to create new object.

```
@Configuration
public class ModelBuilderConfiguration {

    @Bean(initMethod = "initMethod")
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public ProductBuilder productBuilder(){
        return new ProductBuilderImpl();
    }
}
```

and I used `@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` but this is also not working.

And using `ThreadLocal` works with `@Autowired` but is it recommended?

```
public class ProductBuilderImpl implements ProductBuilder{

    private ThreadLocal<Product> product = new ThreadLocal<Product>(){
        @Override
        protected Product initialValue() {
            return new Product();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public ProductBuilder setBasicDetails(String name, String sku) {
        product.get().setName(name);
        product.get().setSku(sku);
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**: Create new object in constructor.

```
public class ProductBuilderImpl implements ProductBuilder{

    private Product product;

    public ProductBuilderImpl() {
        product = new Product();
    }

    @Override
    public ProductBuilder setBasicDetails(String name, String sku) {
        product.setName(name);
        product.setSku(sku);
        return this;
    }
}
```

And use it in `xyzServiceImpl` like `ProductBuilder productBuilder = new ProductBuilderImpl();` so I'll get the new object every time.

So which is best approach considering spring? Or suggest better way for initializing `Product` object.

Comment: You should autowire all the objects which you want spring container to manage for u. As if you create it yourself its lifecycle would not be managed by Spring Container

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new `Product` object every time a request is made, then you can rely to Spring for its initialization and forget the builder thing. Just make it a managed bean and set it's scope to request. You can do that like this:

```
@ManagedBean // or @Component
@RequestScope // or @Scope("request")
public class Product {
    ...
}
```

And inject it to your service.

```
@Service
public class XyzServiceImpl implements XyzService{

    private final Product product;

    // A proxy is injected, not the actual object.
    @Inject // or @Autowired or none
    public XyzServiceImpl(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

}
```